# Is a PostgreSQL function marked as STABLE allowed to acquire locks?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

The PostgreSQL documentation has this to say on the subject of marking functions as STABLE:

> STABLE indicates that the function cannot modify the database, and
>   that within a single table scan it will consistently return the same
>   result for the same argument values, but that its result could change
>   across SQL statements. This is the appropriate selection for functions
>   whose results depend on database lookups, parameter variables (such as
>   the current time zone), etc. (It is inappropriate for AFTER triggers
>   that wish to query rows modified by the current command.) Also note
>   that the current_timestamp family of functions qualify as stable,
>   since their values do not change within a transaction.

I have a function (call it `F`) that needs to lock a table `IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` before starting, to guarantee no new rows are inserted between the time the function is called and the end of the transaction. `F` doesn't make any direct changes to the database. It would be safe for the planner to elide multiple calls to `F` with the same arguments within the same transaction, as long as it is called once.

As an example, let's use

```
CREATE FUNCTION F(x INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE foobar IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foobar WHERE id = x);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

My question is, does that lock acquisition disqualify the function from being marked `STABLE`? That is, is acquiring a lock considered "modifying the database" in this context?

*Edited to add*: What about using an advisory lock? Does that change the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was a simple answer. I tried it, and PG was decidedly unhappy.

```
ERROR:  LOCK TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "LOCK TABLE foobar IN EXCLUSIVE MODE"
```

So the answer is, yes, using `LOCK TABLE` definitely disqualifies a function from being marked STABLE.

Using an advisory lock, however, does not (at least, I do not get an error when I try it).

Answer (score 3):

As you can easily test, that won't work. You'll get this error:

```
ERROR:  LOCK TABLE is not allowed in a non-volatile function
```

But that is no problem. If you want your function to see a stable snapshot of the table, just start a transaction with

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ READ ONLY;
```

Then the table won't change for you.